# Find the most recent non-blank value in each of several columns

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with data like this, sorted by Customer and RecDate:

| Customer | RecDate | Sales | Orders | Widgets | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/01/2023 | 100 |  | 18 |  |
| A | 2/02/2023 |  | 2000 | 75 | 5 |
| A | 2/15/2023 | 50 |  | 0 |  |
| A | 3/01/2023 |  | 400 |  |  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| B | 1/15/2023 | 25 | 75 |  |  |
| B | 3/10/2023 |  | 18 |  | 0 |

In the actual data there are several hundred columns and several million customers.

The goal is to find the most recent non-blank value for each customer in each column:

| Customer | RecDate | Sales | Orders | Widgets | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | N/A | 50 | 400 | 0 | 5 |
| B | N/A | 25 | 18 |  | 0 |

I prefer to write a query to do this using Google Cloud Platform BigQuery SQL. I can also run this through a python script if that's more efficient.  (Remember, this table is huge.)

So far I haven't tried anything as I have absolutely no idea how to even start to do this with either SQL or python.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

(BTW, just finding a way to describe this problem succinctly has been difficult and may be part of the reason why I've not been able to find an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
SELECT Customer,
       LAST_VALUE(Sales IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS Sales,
       LAST_VALUE(Orders IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS Orders,
       LAST_VALUE(Widgets IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS Widgets,
       LAST_VALUE(Other IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS Other
  FROM sample_table
QUALIFY RecDate = MAX(RecDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', RecDate));
```

**Query results**

[image]

- [LAST VALUE with IGNORE NULLS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#last_value)

Comment: I like this, had never heard of "LAST_VALUE" before.  My only concern is, there are almost 300 columns in my data set.  If I need a separate SQL line for each column, what kind of problems will this cause (if any)?  I'm anxious to give this a try, will let you know how it works out.